# How do I access a singleton I created in my AutoLoad script in a scene's C# code? (Godot 3)

Tags: c#, mono, godot

So I'm using the Mono version of Godot 3. My scripts are in C#. I'm attempting to follow this tutorial: http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html

But the code is in GDScript and my best attempts to adapt it have been unsuccessful. I've got the scripts compiling correctly (had to add them to my `.csproj`) but I just can't seem to access the PlayerVars object I set in `Global.cs` in `TitleScene.cs`

`Global.cs` Configured as an Autoload
    using System;
    using Godot;

```
public class Global : Node {

  private PlayerVars playerVars;

  public override void _Ready () {
    this.playerVars = new PlayerVars();
    int total = 5;
    Godot.GD.Print(what: "total is " + total);
    this.playerVars.total = total;
    GetNode("/root/").Set("playerVars",this.playerVars);
  }

}
```

`PlayerVars.cs` A class to store variables.

```
public class PlayerVars {
  public int total;
}
```

`TitleScene.cs` - Attached to my default scene:

```
using System;
using Godot;

public class TitleScene : Node {

    public override void _Ready () {
        Node playervars = (Node) GetNode("/root/playerVars");
        Godot.GD.Print("total in titlescene is" + playervars.total);
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm doing something obvious wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, figured it out.

You reference the node by the name you give it on this screen in Project Properties:

[image: properties screen]

In my case it was `global`.

So now my `Global.cs` looks like this:

```
using System;
using Godot;

public class Global : Node
{

  private PlayerVars playerVars;

  public override void _Ready()
  {
    // Called every time the node is added to the scene.
    // Initialization here
    Summator summator = new Summator();
    playerVars = new PlayerVars();

    playerVars.total = 5;

    Godot.GD.Print(what: "total is " + playerVars.total);

  }

  public PlayerVars GetPlayerVars(){
    return playerVars;
  }

}
```

And my `TitleScene.cs` looks like this:

```
using System;
using Godot;

public class TitleScene : Node
{

  public override void _Ready()
  {
    // Must be cast to the Global type we derived from Node earlier to
    // use its custom methods and props
    Global global = (Global) GetNode("/root/global");
    Godot.GD.Print(global.GetPlayerVars().total);
  }

}
```

Comment: Good job finding it! I see that the C# version was added in the tutorial in the meantime, and it does basically that (just using `var` for type deduction). Amusingly, reading your answer solved my problem although I'm using GDScript, as I was accessing "/root/Root/global" instead of "/root/global" (but in GDScript, it's even easier as you can just use the type as if it was a static call: `Global.GetPlayerVars()`)